# How to enable assert statement to execute?

Tags: java

I've written the following code:

```
class Cl
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        assert true; //1
        Bar.foo();
    }

    static class Bar{
        public static void foo(){
            boolean enabled = false;
            assert enabled = true;
            System.out.println("Asserts " + 
               (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
        }
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/5E8Vb1)**

[JLS 14.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.10) says:

> An assert statement that is executed after its class has completed
>   initialization is enabled if and only if the host system has
>   determined that the top level class that *lexically contains the assert*
>   *statement* enables assertions.

I thought I enabled assertion by assert true in `Cl` class, but it's still not working. How can I enable an assertion regarding to what `JLS` said?

Comment: `assert enabled == true;` try that, as assertion fails only if the logical statement results in `false` as far as I know.

Answer (score 5):

Add the **-ea** option to your java command line when you run your program

Answer (score 2):

Run Your program like this,

```
java -ea YourClass
```

`-ea` means *enable assertion* and after running like this your assertions will be executed during runtime otherwise it just jump the assert statements.

If you are using *`eclipse`* go to Run Configuration and write `-ea` in `VM Arguments` and Run.

If you are trying to enable assertion programmatically you can try this,

```
     boolean enabled = false;
     ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().setDefaultAssertionStatus(true);
     assert enabled = true;
     System.out.println("Asserts " + 
        (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
```

Comment: But note that once a class has been initialized, it is not possible to change its assertion status.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers explain how to enable assertions.  (Note that you can enable or disable them for all classes, for the classes in a given package, or for individual classes.)

I just want to explain what `assert true;` actually does.

It doesn't enable or disable assertions.  That's not what an `assert` statement "means".  Indeed, by the time you execute that statement, it would be too late to enable or disable assertions for either `C1`, and probably for `Bar` as well.  Assertions can only be enabled or disabled for a class *before* the class has be initialized.  That happens (at most) once for any given class.

What it actually does (if assertions are enabled ...) is to evaluate the expression `true` and test whether it is `true`.  Which it always will be.  In short, it is a no-op.